# Getting message 0 was unexpected at this time batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the following batch script  and i keep getting the error "0 was unexpected at this time."

```
IF "%Logs%"=="true" (
    for /f %%i in ('dir \%Device%\logs') do set cmd=%%i
        if %cmd% GTR 0 (
            echo Folder does exist.
        )
)
```

I think I have to fix it with delayed expansion but I don't know how, I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: is the shown code snipped inside another code block?

Comment: @Stephan yes, I update the code

Comment: You need to use delayed expansion with your `%cmd%` variable.

Comment: @Stephan I will repost my comment, I think I misrepresented my message as I posted on the phone. let me get to the laptop quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *enable* delayed expansion with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and then *use*  it with `!var!` instead of `%var%`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
IF "%Logs%"=="true" (
    for /f %%i in ('dir /ad /b "\%Device%\logs" ^|find /c /v ""') do set cmd=%%i
    if !cmd! GTR 0 (
       echo Folder does exist.
    )
)
```

Note: for an empty folder you will get a value of `2` (because of `.` and `..`). Either adapt to `... GTR 2` or use another approach (like above).